# How do I see if memcached is already running on my chosen port?

Tags: memcached

I am having some problems with memcached and one idea I am having is that perhaps it is already running on the port I am trying to run it on, started by some other user on our network. Is there a way to tell what memcached ports are currently in use?

Comment: Have you tried connecting to them?  Even a denial of access will prove your point.

Comment: Which OS are you running memcached on?

Comment: Linux - I should have specified.

Comment: Also, when I kill my own memcached process with the port I started it on, and try to connect to the port, I do get a denial of access. I am wondering if a process is hanging in some kind of corrupted state and therefore somehow blocking access to the port.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try

```
netstat -ap | grep TheChosenPort#
```

and see if anything is listening on those TCP or UDP ports.

Comment: quick question, if there's something on port 8080 and you grep '80', wont that give a false positive?

Comment: Fyi this doesn't work on OS-X. (the question was for Linux) Try simoes answer.

Comment: it will give false positif if another application using the same port.

Answer (score 91):

To see if it is running you could also try telnetting into the port:

```
telnet localhost 11211
```

If this works you will see the following (telling you that the given port is open):

```
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Now if memcached IS running you can see some basic stats by issuing the given command:

```
stats
```

If this fails you will know that memcached is not running.

Comment: @simoes very nicely written answer. Voted up!

Comment: To exit, just type quit

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Well done.

Answer (score 18):

#### netstat

In Linux, check via `netstat`, e.g.

```
$ sudo netstat -nap | grep memcached
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN      5067/memcached
```

#### ps

Use `ps` to filter the processes:

```
$ ps wuax | grep memcache
497 5067  0.0  1.3 384824 53928 ? Ssl  Apr11   1:28 memcached -d -p 11211 -u memcached -m 64 -c 1024 -P /var/run/memcached/memcached.pid -l 127.0.0.1
```

The port can be found next to `-p`, e.g. `-p 11211`. If port hasn't been specified, default is `11211`.

#### Bash

You can send `stats` command to the given port and see if the memcached responds, e.g.

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/localhost/11211; printf "stats\nquit\n" >&3; cat <&3
```

#### Telnet

Use `telnet` to connect to the host and run `stats` (as above), e.g.

```
$ telnet localhost 11211
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
stats
STAT pid 23669
STAT uptime 433859
```

<sup>Then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to finish.</sup>

Answer (score 7):

Use the following command

```
ps -U user | grep -v grep | grep memcached
```

Answer (score 5):

You can check memcached **status**

```
service memcached status
```

You will see a line like this at the bottom:

> ```
>        └─1560 /usr/bin/memcached -vv -m 64 -p 11211 -u memcache -l 127.0.0.1 -P /var/run/memcached/memcached.pid
> ```

The **-p 11211** is what port it's running on.

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking this question, it sounds like you're running a really old version.  If you did this on a recent version, you'd see this:

```
% ./memcached
failed to listen on TCP port 11211: Address already in use
```